# Como inserir rand no C?

Tags: c, portugol

Em portugol:

```
Algoritmo "semnome"
    // Linguagem e Lógica de Programação
    // Lu e Gustavo 
    // Descrição   : Aqui você descreve o que o programa faz! (função)
    // Autor(a)    : Nome do(a) aluno(a)
    // Data atual  : 27/09/2020
    Var
       // Seção de Declarações das variáveis
       Joken, Joken_at: Inteiro

Inicio
      // Seção de Comandos, procedimento, funções, operadores, etc...
      Escreval("Neste jogo você ira jogar JoKenPo contra a maquina")
      Escreval("Digite [1] para pedra")
      Escreval("Digite [2] para papel")
      Escreval("Digite [3] para tesoura")
      Leia(Joken)
      Enquanto (Joken<=0) ou (Joken>=4) faça
               Escreval("Opção inválida")
               Escreva("Digite novamente: ")
               Leia (Joken)
      Fimenquanto
      Escolha Joken
             Caso 1
                  Escreval("Você é pedra")
             Caso 2
                  Escreval("Você é papel")
             Caso 3
                  Escreval("Você é tesoura")
      Fimescolha
      Aleatorio 1, 3
      Leia(Joken_at)
      Aleatorio off
      Escolha Joken_at
             Caso 1
                  Escreval("O computador é pedra")
             Caso 2
                  Escreval("O computador é papel")
             Caso 3
                  Escreval("O computador é tesoura")
      Fimescolha
      Enquanto (Joken=Joken_at) Faça
               Escreval("O jogo empatou")
               Escreval("Para parar de jogar aperte esc")
               Escreval("Se quiser jogar novamente aperte [1] para pedra , [2] para papel ou [3] para tesoura")
               Leia(Joken)
               Enquanto (Joken<=0) ou (Joken>=4) Faça
                        Escreval ("Opção invalida")
                        Escreva ("Digite novamente: ")
                        Leia(Joken)
               Fimenquanto
               Escolha Joken
                       Caso 1
                            Escreval("Você é pedra")
                       Caso 2
                            Escreval("Você é papel")
                       Caso 3
                            Escreval("Você é tesoura")
               Fimescolha
               Aleatorio 1, 3
               Leia(Joken_at)
               Aleatorio off
               Escolha Joken_at
                       Caso 1
                            Escreval("O computador é pedra")
                       Caso 2
                            Escreval("O computador é papel")
                       Caso 3
                            Escreval("O computador é tesoura")
               Fimescolha
      Fimenquanto
      Se (((Joken=1) e (Joken_at=3)) OU ((Joken=2) e (Joken_at=1)) ou ((Joken=3) e (Joken_at=2))) Então
         Escreva("Você é o vitorioso")
      senão
      Escreva("Você perdeu")
      Fimse
Fimalgoritmo
```

Em C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>
int main (){
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"Portuguese");
    int J, Ja;
    printf("Neste jogo você ira jogar JoKenPo contra a maquina \n");
    printf("Digite [1] para pedra \n");
    printf("Digite [2] para papel \n");
    printf("Digite [3] para tesoura \n");
    scanf("%d",&J);
    while ((J<=0)||(J>=4)){ 
        printf("Opção invalida \n");
        printf("Digite novamente: ");
        scanf("%d",&J);
    }
    switch(J){
        case 1: printf("Você é pedra");break;
        case 2: printf("Você é papel");break;
        case 3: printf("Você é tesoura");break;
    }
    //Aleatório
    switch(Ja){
        case 1: printf("O computador é pedra");break;
        case 2: printf("O computador é papel");break;
        case 3: printf("O computador é tesoura");break;
    }
    while (J==Ja){
        printf("O jogo empatou\n");
        printf("Para jogar novamente aperte [1] para pedra , [2] para papel ou [3] para tesoura");
        scanf("%d",&J);
        while((J<=0)||(J>=4)){
            printf("Opção inválida\n");
            printf("Digite novamente: ");
            scanf("%d",&J);
        }
        switch(J){
            case 1: printf("Você é pedra");break;
            case 2: printf("Você é papel");break;
            case 3: printf("Você é tesoura");break;
        }
        //Aleatório     
    }
    if(((J==1) && (Ja==3)) || ((J==2) && (Ja==1)) || ((J==3) && (Ja==2)))
        printf("Você é o vitorioso");
    else
        ("Você é o perdedor");  
    getch ();
    return 0;
}
```

A pergunta é: como eu faço pra botar o `//aleatório` em `C`, como está no portugol?

Comment: Antes de fazer outras perguntas, leia [isto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Veja um exemplo aqui: https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/rand/

Comment: Se uma das respostas abaixo resolveu o seu problema e não restou nenhuma dúvida, escolha a que você mais gostou e marque-a como correta/aceita ao clicar no "✅" que está ao lado dela, o que também marca a sua pergunta como resolvida. Se ainda te resta alguma dúvida ou gostaria de maiores esclarecimentos, fique a vontade para comentar. 

Answer (score 0):

Assumindo que "Aleatório 1, 3" significa gerar um número aleatório entre 1 e 3, pode ser programado em C assim:

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
...
Ja = rand() % 3 + 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Existe várias maneiras de você gerar [números *aleatorios*](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/N%C3%BAmero_aleat%C3%B3rio) no `C`.

Primeiro adicione no seu código as libs:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>
```

Em seguida no começo do código adicione essa linha:

```c
srand(time(NULL));
```

Isso vai fazer com que os números aleatórios sejam diferentes.

quando quiser gerar um número aleatório use: `rand() % max + 1`

Onde `max` será o valor máximo que você quer gerar, no seu caso, `max = 3;`

Caso você queira saber melhor sobre o `rand()` e o `srand()` acesse esse [link](http://linguagemc.com.br/valores-aleatorios-em-c-com-a-funcao-rand/).

Caso queira ver a documentação, acesse [este](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/rand/).